# after_create and after_save order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have done some tests, and I have find out that after_create is called before than after_save (in Rails 2.3.9)

Is that correct ?

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, here's the order:

```
# (1) before_validation
# (2) before_validation_on_create
# (3) after_validation
# (4) after_validation_on_create
# (5) before_save
# (6) before_create
# (7) after_create
# (8) after_save
```

Found here:

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Does after create then only get fired during .create and .save then?

Answer (score 0):

And remember that the callback after_create is executed only time. This is difference between after_save and after_create